# Which node should be used for connections for ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

first time playing with ElasticSearch.

I read docs and created ES cluster which consists one master and two data nodes:

```
# Master
...
node.master: true
node.ingest: true
node.data: false
...

# Data
...
node.master: false
node.ingest: false
node.data: true
...
```

Also, I have an app which will use this ES in future.

My main question - which node I should use while connecting to ES?

I believe it should be Master node, but, I can also connect to Data node. 
Is it possible to send data to the Master node and get from Data?
What is the best way to use these nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a simple set up, you can use Data nodes for write and read purpose, Load balancer can be used to distribute the traffic among the data nodes.

In our 100 nodes elasticsearch set up, Data nodes with load balancer are using for bulk writes to ES and querying purpose.

Master nodes can only be used for coordination purpose.

I didn't see any performance improvements with ingest nodes.